# fixing page URL's

Tags: themes, url-rewriting, urls

I've got this page to fix, however i'm quite new to WordPress, so i was wondering maybe anyone here will be able to help me.

There's URL's in the header which should navigate you to pages like https://www.page.lt/[flat-rent]/[city], but these are not working yet. However i've noticed that when you open advert, you have breadcrumbs, with structure like [flat-rent] / [city] and if you press on it it will navigate you to that page, however it adds prefix to URL, so URL becomes this: https://www.page.lt/property-type/[flat-rent]/[city]. So my question is how do i lose that "property-type" prefix? Idea is that if i do lose "property-type" prefix, those pages in the header would start working.

p.s. if my question lacks some information please ask once again i'm quite new at this so i might not provided some crucial information.

p.s.s. site is using "Houzez" theme.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to contact the authors of the premium theme you are using. This may be in reference to a custom post type and you'll probably need some custom code to change the url slug.

Comment: Tried that, however support is already expired, and extending support costs almost as much as the entire theme.